# Changing a ObjectMap to store in json Libgdx

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, hashmap

I am having some issues with the general concept of JSON files and writing to them. Currently, I have an ObjectMap of my game items, the issue is with changing this map. I have a class called item shown below,

```
  public static class Item {
     public String name;
     public String type;
     public String rarity;
     public int reqLevel;
     int priceBuy;
     int priceSell;
     int amount = 0;
     public item() {}
     public void setAmount(int amnt) {amount = amnt;}
  }
```

So I have a json file of all these items in my game, I can load them in perfectly fine. What I want to do is change the amount of an Item I have using the setAmount or any other way, currently all the items are loaded into the ObjectMap. I posted below my save() and load(). I think I would need to change the item within the map before writing it back but I am struggling with getting it to do anything.

```
  public void save()
  {
      Json json = new Json();
      json.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
      file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(items), false);
  }

  public void load() {
      Json json = new Json();
      items = json.fromJson(ObjectMap.class, file);
  }
```

EDIT: @Sneh
Actually I think it perfectly acceptable to do a fromJson of an ObjectMap.class, this is what the JSON file looks like, it is so you can have multiple items etc.

*Could be wrong but it is loading and writing perfectly in scenarios I purposely create, what im having issues with is the changing of a specfic items amount variable!

```
//Test file with small amount of items
{
"SwordOfDeath": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.InventoryController$Sword",
    "name": "Sword of Death",
    "type" : "Sword",
    "rarity": "Common",
    "reqLevel": 1,
    "proficiency": "Strength",
    "damageMax": 15,
    "damageMin": 2,
    "priceBuy": 1,
    "priceSell": 2,
    "bonusMagic": 0,
    "bonusStrength": 0,
    "bonusDexterity": 0,
    "bonusDefense": 0,
    "bonusLuck": 0,
    "amount": 2
},
"DaggerOfDeath": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.InventoryController$Dagger",
    "name": "Dagger of Death",
    "type": "Dagger",
    "rarity": "Rare",
    "reqLevel": 3,
    "proficiency": "Dexterity",
    "damageMax": 15,
    "damageMin": 2,
    "priceBuy": 1,
    "priceSell": 2,
    "bonusMagic": 0,
    "bonusStrength": 0,
    "bonusDexterity": 0,
    "bonusDefense": 0,
    "bonusLuck": 0,
    "amount": 2
},
"DaggerOfLife": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.InventoryController$Dagger",
    "name": "Dagger of Life",
    "type": "Dagger",
    "rarity": "Epic",
    "reqLevel": 5,
    "proficiency": "Dexterity",
    "damageMax": 15,
    "damageMin": 2,
    "priceBuy": 1,
    "priceSell": 2,
    "bonusMagic": 0,
    "bonusStrength": 0,
    "bonusDexterity": 0,
    "bonusDefense": 0,
    "bonusLuck": 0,
    "amount": 2
},
"LifeSword": {
    "class": "com.johnny.gamerpg.InventoryController$Sword",
    "name": "Life Sword",
    "type": "Sword",
    "rarity": "Legendary",
    "reqLevel": 45,
    "proficiency": "Strength",
    "damageMax": 100,
    "damageMin": 99,
    "priceBuy": 1000,
    "priceSell": 2000,
    "bonusMagic": 0,
    "bonusStrength": 5,
    "bonusDexterity": 0,
    "bonusDefense": 0,
    "bonusLuck": 10,
    "amount": 2
}
}
```

Comment: can you show where you create and change items object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it actually was easier then I thought, the problem was with how I was updating the object map, I needed to get the current value give it a new value and the put it back in and delete the old. This is shown in the example below.

```
public void changeAmount(String key, int amount) {
    item temp = items.get(key);
    items.remove(key);
    temp.setAmount(amount);
    items.put(key, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problem because you are not using the fromJson method properly. The fromJson method can parse the json to the class which you specify. So if you specify Item.class, it will give you object of Item class and then you can make changes in that object and save it back.

Here is a little example.

```
public void loadAndSaveJson() {
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.external("test.json");

    Json json = new Json();

    Item itemToUpdate = json.fromJson(Item.class, file);
    itemToUpdate.setAmount(10000);

    json.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
    file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(itemToUpdate), false);

    Item itemUpdated = json.fromJson(Item.class, file);
}
```

I tested it out and its updating the value fine on the json file.

Also its worth reading more here [Reading & Writing JSON with LibGdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)